# QGIS 3.20 - Online Help-Content doesn't show up

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, installation, proxy, internet-explorer

We are running QGIS on a terminal-server. Since we changed from version 3.18 to 3.20, the help content doesn’t show up anymore. We also use a whitelist including https://qgis.org/ and https://feed.qgis.org/

In version 3.18 everything worked out perfectly, we just used the predefined options.

In version 3.20 everytime the "errorpage" shows up, it seems that it doesn’t matter what address is filled in at the options menu. Even if we set the path of our help for example to https://qgis.org/ (which is included in our whitelist), the errorpage shows up. **BUT** if we put in https://qgis.org/ in the browser, which showed up the errorpage before, https://qgis.org will be shown correctly afterwards.

[image: QGIS-Errorpage]

So when we press F1 for help, the errorpage shows up. We thought about any problems with our proxy. But, like I already mentioned, when we put in any adress out of our whitelist, this adress will be shown correctly in the browser-window which was opened by QGIS before to show the errorpage.

Does anyone has a hint what has changed from 3.18 to 3.20?

Comment: unblock https://docs.qgis.org (example https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/index.html)

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help. It seems like QGIS can't transfer any address properly to the Internet Explorer